# C# Converting or Parsing a Variable to DateTime

Tags: c#

I need to write a short piece of code to take a variable and then convert it into a DateTime type. Unfortunately it keeps saying its fine in the build but when I run it, it gives me an error because its not seeing it as a variable, but as a string.

```
DateTime dateValue = (Convert.ToDateTime("@DeliveryDate"));
```

Comment: What is `@DeliveryDate`?

Comment: `"@DeliveryDate"` *is* a string

Comment: You should pass a concrete variable.

Comment: The comment wasnt aimed at you @TheSolution, I was pointing out he wasn't passing a variable called delivery date like in T-SQL, he was just passing a string saying `"@DelivertDate"`

Comment: deliveryDate is a column in a database and @deliverydate is the result of an SQL query that returns a certain date.

Comment: And this result, you certainly have stored it in a variable somewhere yes?

Comment: Yes, its stored and I use it successfully in other functions but it simply doesn't like it when I use it in this specific way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've misunderstood something about how variables work. In C#, variables need to be referenced by their identifier in code. C# does not support string substitution of variables like you might find in a language like [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Assuming you've define a variable in code, and populated it with a value from the database:

```
…
string deliveryDate = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

You can convert it to a `DateTime` like this:

```
DateTime dateValue = Convert.ToDateTime(deliveryDate);
```

Comment: +1. To put it more bluntly, in general, `!object.Equals(deliveryDate, "@deliveryDate")`. The former is a variable containing a string, the latter is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
String deliveryDate = "2013-07-31 23:12:00";
DateTime dateValue = Convert.ToDateTime(deliveryDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
string DeliveryDate = @"01/01/2011"; // I assume DeliveryDate is some variable you defined before
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(DeliveryDate)
```